# How to Properly Terminate a Thread which is Blocking (Lparallel Common Lisp)

Tags: multithreading, common-lisp, blockingqueue

In the Lparallel API, the recommended way to terminate all threaded tasks is to stop the kernel with `(lparallel:end-kernel)`. But when a thread is blocking—eg, with `(pop-queue queue1)` waiting for an item to appear in the queue—it will still be active when the kernel is stopped. In this case (at least in SBCL) the kernel shutdown occasionally (but not every time) fails with:

```
debugger invoked on a SB-KERNEL:BOUNDING-INDICES-BAD-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "lparallel" RUNNING {1002F04973}>:
  The bounding indices 1 and NIL are bad for a sequence of length 0.
See also:
  The ANSI Standard, Glossary entry for "bounding index designator"
  The ANSI Standard, writeup for Issue SUBSEQ-OUT-OF-BOUNDS:IS-AN-ERROR

debugger invoked on a SB-SYS:INTERACTIVE-INTERRUPT in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10012E0613}>:
  Interactive interrupt at #x1001484328.
```

I’m assuming this has something to do with the blocking thread not terminating correctly. How should a blocking thread be properly terminated before shutting down the kernel? (The API says `kill-tasks` should only be used in exceptional circumstances, which I’m taking not to apply to this “normal” shutdown circumstance.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with killing a thread is that it might happen anywhere, when the thread could be in any unknown state.
The only way to safely terminate a thread it is to let it shutdown itself gracefully, meaning you expect that during normal operations, there is a way for the thread to know it should stop working. Then you can properly clean your resources, close databases, free foreign pointers, log all things, ...

The queues you are using have operations that can timeout, that is a simple yet safe way to ensure you can avoid blocking forever and exit properly. But that's not the only option (you can use them in addition to what is shown below).

#### Shared / global flag

When a timeout occurs, or when you receive a message, you check a global boolean variable (or one that is shared among all interested threads). That's also a simple way to exit, and it can be read by multiple threads. This is however a concurrent access, so you should use locks or atomic operations (http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Atomic-Operations), for example use `defglobal` and a fixnum type with `atomic-incf`, etc.

#### Control messages

Send control data in the queues and use them to determine how to shutdown gracefully, and how to propagate the information down the pipes, or how to restart things. This is safe (just message-passing) and allows any kind of control you might want to implement in your thread.

```
(defpackage :so (:use :cl :bt :lparallel.queue))
(in-package :so)
```

Let's define two services.

The first one echoes back its input:

```
(defun echo (in out)
  (lambda ()
    (loop
      for value = (pop-queue in)
      do (push-queue value out)
      until (eq value :stop))))
```

Notice how it is expected to finish properly when given a `:stop` input, and how it also propagates the `:stop` message to its output queue.

The second thread will perform a modular addition, and also sleeps a bit between requests:

```
(defun modulo-adder (x m in out)
  (lambda ()
    (loop
      for value = (progn (sleep 0.02)
                         (pop-queue in))
      do (push-queue (typecase value
                       (keyword value)
                       (number (mod (+ x value) m)))
                     out)
      until (eq value :stop))))
```

Create queues:

```
(defparameter *q1* (make-queue))
(defparameter *q2* (make-queue))
```

Create threads:

```
(progn
  (bt:make-thread (echo *q1* *q2*) :name "echo")
  (bt:make-thread (modulo-adder 5 1024 *q2* *q1*) :name "adder"))
```

Both threads are connected to each others in a circular fashion, creating an infinite loop of additions. No value is currently exchanged between threads, and you can see them running for example with `slime-list-threads` or any other implementation-provided way; In any case `(bt:all-threads)` returns a list.

```
slime-list-threads

10 adder                          Running 
11 echo                           Running 
...
```

Add an item, now there is an infinite exchange of data between threads:

```
(push-queue 10 *q1*)
```

Wait, then stop them both:

```
(push-queue :stop *q1*)
```

Both threads stopped gracefully (they are no more visible in lists of threads).
We can inspect what remains in the queues (result vary from one test to another):

```
(list (try-pop-queue *q1*)
      (try-pop-queue *q2*))
(99 NIL)

(list (try-pop-queue *q1*)
      (try-pop-queue *q2*))
(:STOP NIL)

(list (try-pop-queue *q1*)
      (try-pop-queue *q2*))
(NIL NIL)
```

#### Interrupting a thread

You create a service, controlled by messages or a global flag, but then you have a bug and the thread hangs. Instead of killing it and lose everything, you want at least to unwind the thread stack properly. This is a dangerous too, but you can use `bt:interrupt` to stop a thread *anywhere it is running right now* and execute a function.

```
(define-condition stop () ())
(defun signal-stop ()
  (signal 'stop))

(defun endless ()
  (let ((output *standard-output*))
    (lambda ()
      (print "START" output)
      (unwind-protect (handler-case (loop)
                        (stop ()
                          (print "INTERRUPTED" output)))
        (print "STOP" output)))))
```

Start it:

```
(bt:make-thread (endless) :name "loop")
```

This prints `"START"` and loops.
Then we interrupt it:

```
(bt:interrupt-thread (find "loop"
                           (bt:all-threads)
                           :test #'string=
                           :key #'bt:thread-name)
                     #'signal-stop)
```

The following is printed:

```
"INTERRUPTED" 
"STOP"
```

Those messages would not be printed if the thread was killed, but note that you could still manage to have corrupted data given how random the interruption is. Also, it can unblock blocking calls like `sleep` or `pop-queue`.